# How to count categorical timeseries data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This week I decided to dive a bit into pandas. I have a pandas DataFrame with historical IRC logs that looks like this:

```
timestamp           action   nick        message
2005-11-04 01:44:33 False    hack-cclub  lex, hey!
2005-11-04 01:44:43 False    hack-cclub  lol, yea thats broke
2005-11-04 01:44:56 False    lex         Slashdot - Updated 2005-11-04 00:23:00 | Micro...
2005-11-04 01:44:56 False    hack-cclub  lex slashdot
2005-11-04 01:45:12 False    lex         port 666 is doom - doom Id Software (or mdqs o..
2005-11-04 01:45:12 False    hack-cclub  lex, port 666
2005-11-04 01:45:21 False    hitokiri    lex, port 23485
2005-11-04 01:45:45 False    hitokiri    lex, port 1024
2005-11-04 01:45:46 True     hack-cclub  slaps lex around with a wet fish
```

There are roughly 5.5M rows and I'm trying to make some basic visualizations like rank over time for the top 25 nicks and that sort of thing. I know I can get the top 25 nicks like this:

```
df['nick'].value_counts()[:25]
```

What I want is a rolling count like this:

```
hack-cclub lex hitokiri
1          0   0
2          0   0
2          1   0
3          1   0
3          2   0
4          2   0
4          2   1
4          2   2
5          2   2
```

So that I can plot an area graph of messages from the beginning of time for the top 25 nicks. I know I can do this by just iterating over the entire dataframe and keeping a count but since the whole point of doing this is to learn to use pandas I was hoping there would be a more idiomatic way to do it. It would also be nice to have the same data but with ranks rather than running counts like this:

```
hack-cclub lex hitokiri
1          2   2
1          2   2
1          2   3
1          2   3
1          2   3
1          2   3
1          2   3
1          2   2
1          2   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you need [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
print df[['timestamp', 'nick']]
             timestamp        nick
0  2005-11-04 01:44:33  hack-cclub
1  2005-11-04 01:44:43  hack-cclub
2  2005-11-04 01:44:56         lex
3  2005-11-04 01:44:56  hack-cclub
4  2005-11-04 01:45:12         lex
5  2005-11-04 01:45:12  hack-cclub
6  2005-11-04 01:45:21    hitokiri
7  2005-11-04 01:45:45    hitokiri
8  2005-11-04 01:45:46  hack-cclub

df = pd.crosstab(df.timestamp, df.nick)
print df
nick                 hack-cclub  hitokiri  lex
timestamp                                     
2005-11-04 01:44:33           1         0    0
2005-11-04 01:44:43           1         0    0
2005-11-04 01:44:56           1         0    1
2005-11-04 01:45:12           1         0    1
2005-11-04 01:45:21           0         1    0
2005-11-04 01:45:45           0         1    0
2005-11-04 01:45:46           1         0    0

df = df.cumsum()
print df
nick                 hack-cclub  hitokiri  lex
timestamp                                     
2005-11-04 01:44:33           1         0    0
2005-11-04 01:44:43           2         0    0
2005-11-04 01:44:56           3         0    1
2005-11-04 01:45:12           4         0    2
2005-11-04 01:45:21           4         1    2
2005-11-04 01:45:45           4         2    2
2005-11-04 01:45:46           5         2    2
```

Comment: I dont understand last rank dataframe. Can you explain it?